# Routes on Production of Angular 7 Application Fail With Http 500 or 404 Server Errors

Tags: angular

Trying to deploy a sample angular application to a public site to test Angular production. But shows error when using routes.

- I built a new application using `ng new toys`
- Added a new component `ng g component homepage`
- Included this in `app-routing.modeul.ts`
- Built for production using `ng build --base-href /toys`
- Also tried with `ng build --prod`
- Deployed to a shared host running Apache

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The main site loads http://www.ngstrorefront.com/toys/ properly.
[image]

but when using route http://www.ngstrorefront.com/toys/home, the site fails to load with a HTTP 500 Server Error. There is another `.htaccess` file under `\public_html` that applies all other sites, i do not want to change this.

[image]

When added a `.htaccess` to the domain's main folder `/public_html/ngstorefront` on the server with this content. With or without this file, routes do not load but we see a 404 server error.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trials, i found the solution. This was actually discussed on Angular Github at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27991

1.Build your project using command like `ng build --prod --base-href /toys/` . If you wanted to load the site as `www.mysite.com/toys`.

2.The above will generate `project-home/dist/toys`. Create a file `.htaccess` under this folder with the below contents

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

3.Copy the sources under `project-home/dist/toys` to your website domain folder. On shared hosting, it will usually be like `/public_html/yoursitename/`.

In my example i had the file like this `/public_html/ngstrorefront/toys/.htaccess`. Note that `.htaccess` should be under the folder at the level of your Angular projects' `index.html` and not under your website's root.

You site should work with routes as well.

Note:

1. Usually shared hosting will not allow us to change any Apache http.conf settings. If they do then using that instead of `.htaccess` is the best route.
2. Change the permissions on `.htaccess` file to read only. I've seen several sites attacked using this file.